# GUID not updated on import

Tags: import, export, guids

I've exported data from my dev server and imported it to my prod server.
One template is listing child pages and uses `$page->guid` to get link to page.

The problem is that this link still points to my internal dev server.

Has anyone else had similar problems? And if yes, how do I solve it without having to edit my DB directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GUID is not an URL. Use `get_permalink()` to get the correct URLs.

Just ignore the GUID. It is – as the name says – an identifier.